# Blender merging material faces if it shares the same uv/texture?

Tags: materials, export, faces

Since I've updated to the most recent version of blender, whenever I export a DAE, if it has multiple faces that share the same UV/texture it will merge these. It prevents me from being able to have customizable faces on this mesh in the game etc.

Unless I assign "fake" textures to each face separately, this is the only way around it.

Is there a setting that I need to uncheck to go back to how it was?